# Создание триггера на обновление SQL

Tags: sql, триггер

Подскажите, как создать триггер на обновление, когда указанная дата в ячейке таблицы равняется текущей дате (МСК), то происходит изменение параметра active_mute c 1 на 0

```
If CURRENT_DATE >= mute_end THEN UPDATE `mute` SET `active_mute` = 0 WHERE `mute`.`id` = 15;
```

(Типо такого)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите СУБД, включая версию. *как создать триггер на обновление, когда указанная дата в ячейке таблицы равняется текущей дате (МСК), то происходит изменение параметра active_mute c 1 на 0* Никак. Триггер - это дополнительное действие по факту выполнения указанного основного (вставка, обновление, удаление). Тут же никакого действия нет. Это задача для планировщика, а не для триггера.

Comment: PS. Судя по квотированию имени таблицы, это MySQL. См. [EVENT SCHEDULER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html)